# Request passphrase from remote device on boot (phone, workstation, etc) in Linux

Tags: linux, boot, mount, authentication, encfs

I have an encrypted encfs mount on a server running Ubuntu 18.04.

I manually have to login to mount the drive, entering my passphrase. Storing the passphrase on the server would make the encryption pointless.

I'd like to setup a routine to automomount on boot, but preferably the routine or script would halt mounting of my encrypted drive and request authorization or in best case even the passphrase string from a remote device (such as a phone, a workstation, via email etc).

In other words, when the machine boots it requests the passphrase or yes/no authorization from somewhere else. Until that has completed, it waits...

Example:

- Ubuntu 18.04 server boots
- Gets to my custom script where it mounts the encrypted drive after boot.
- Sends push notification to phone, workstation, or email etc (so far I haven't found any solution) asking for authorization to mount the drive.
- On the external device I can (1) YES / NO authorize the mount process, or even better (2) enter the mount passphrase which will be passed back to encfs.

---

If there is no such method, I may settle just sending an email or pushover notification from the server to prompt to login via SSH and authorize the mount or mount manually...

Comment: So basically like a two-factor authentication for your own system’s personal purpose?

Comment: It's kind of like two-factor, yes, but it's a server not a personal use computer. I just assumed there would be an established method to interactively mount encrypted drives etc on servers nowadays - kind of like pushover, but taking user input and passing it back to the machine.